# Why in mmap PROT_READ equals PROT_EXEC

Tags: linux, mmap, memory-mapping

I tried to allocate some memory pages with read only access using `mmap` function. I printed `/proc/self/maps` to check if the memory protection was working. It showed like this even though the protection argument of `mmap` was `PROT_READ`

```
 7fec0c585000-7fec0c785000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
```

**This means that when I ask the kernel to allocate some read only memory pages it mark them as executable too.**

I did some other test and I realized that when I ask for a **write only** pages,`PROT_WRITE`  without `PROT_READ`, the output of `maps` file is like this:

```
7fec0c585000-7fec0c785000 -w-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

**This means in addition with the previous example that PROT_READ is equivalent to PROT_EXEC**

Calling `mmap` with both `PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ`, enables execution too.

*I wonder if there is a way to map a read only, no executable memory page; or one that is read write and no executable?*

---

Information of the computer where the test were run:

1. Linux Arch 4.1.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Aug 17 08:52:28 CEST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
2. Intel Core i5-2310, x86_64

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After doing some research I realized that Linux only activates memory protection when a `GNU_STACK` program header is included in the `ELF` program headers.
By memory protection I mean the use of the NX bit of the processor, so memory pages can be marked as not executable.

For what I understand, `GNU_STACK` program header is designed to tell the kernel that you want some specific properties for the stack, one those properties is a non-executable stack. It appears that if you don't explicitly ask for a non-executable stack, all the `ELF` sections marked as readable will be executable too. And also all the memory mapping with `mmap` while have the same behavior.

Sadly there is no enough documentation on what `GNU_STACK` does, and the documentation of `mmap` doesn't specify its connection with `GNU_STACK` to enable execute protection.

*References:*

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hardened/GNU_stack_quickstart

Comment: Doing some more digging, this is because of READ_IMPLIES_EXEC flag on the personality. You can change this without the GNU_STACK header by getting the persona (passing -1 to sys_personality), then masking out the flag (persona & ~0x0400000) whose value can be found in sys/personality.h, then resetting the persona.

Answer (score 0):

I test this issue in my Debian Jessie.

I mmap an anonymous area in a special address,and print the content of maps, the corresponding permission form:

```
PROT_READ               r--p
PROT_WRITE              -w-p
PROT_EXEC               --xp
PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE    rw-p
PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC     r-xp
```

I don't test PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC ..., because pax/grsecurity protects against creating writable and executable mapping.

test information:
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt17-1 (2015-09-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Intel i7,x86_64

Comment: Check the section header of you elf file. There must be a GNU_STACK section

Comment: GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     10  you're right!

Comment: I have found the trick : GUN_STACK(RW/RWX) -> load_elf_binary verify this permission -> process personality(READ_IMPLIES_EXEC) -> If this bit is set then PROT_READ will also add the PROT_EXEC bit -> So you can know the answer.