# Why could my program execute non-executable data?

Tags: linux, security, assembly, x86-64, fasm

Why does this not fail?
I mean, if I compile and execute the following code, I get

```
mmap 4KB as readable/writeable, but not executable.
write some code there.
and call there. this should fail!
but does not?
thats weird!
```

I expected I had to use `syscall sys_mprotect` to mark some memory to be executable, but this works, even if it should not?

```
format elf64 executable
use64
entry start

macro echo message
{
  mov rdx, message#.size
  lea rsi, [ message ]
  mov rdi, 1
  mov rax, 1
  syscall
}
struc db [ data ]
{
  common
    . db data
    .size = $ - .
}

segment executable
  start:
    echo msg0
    mov r10, 0x22 ;MMAP_Private | MMAP_Anonymous
    mov rdx, 0x03 ;readable | writeable
    mov rsi, 4096
    xor rdi, rdi
    mov rax, 9
    syscall
    mov qword [ buffer ], rax
    echo msg1
    mov rcx, stub.size
    mov rdi, qword [ buffer ]
    lea rsi, [ stub ]
    rep movsb

    echo msg2
    mov rdx, msg3.size
    lea rsi, [ msg3 ]
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rax, 1
    call qword [ buffer ]
    echo msg4
  exit:
    xor rdi, rdi
    mov rax, 60
    syscall
segment readable  writeable
  stub:
    syscall
    ret
  stub.size = $ - stub

  msg0 db 'mmap 4KB as readable/writeable, but not executable.', 10, 0
  msg1 db 'write some code there.', 10, 0
  msg2 db 'and call there. this should fail!', 10, 0
  msg3 db 'but does not?', 10, 0
  msg4 db 'thats weird!', 10, 0
  buffer rq 1
```

So the actual question is: How can I get this to fail? I expected, that Linux uses the NX-bit for such memory and my PC, I checked it with

```
grep ^flags /proc/cpuinfo | head -n1 | egrep --color=auto ' (pae|nx) '
```

and also checked it in the BIOS, allows such kind of memory protection.

Comment: How do you use fasm's debug-symbol output with gdb?  I tried `fasm -s nx-test.debug  nx-test.fasm`, but when I tried `symbol-file nx-test.debug` in gdb, it said "can't read symbols: File format not recognized".  (I don't know FASM at all, just NASM and GNU.  (and some MASM syntax)).

Comment: Had to use `readelf -a` to get the address of `_start` to set a breakpoint :/

Comment: just compile it with `fasm file-name.fasm`, make it executable with `chmod +x file-name` and execute it with `./file-name`. the symbols-file is fasm-specific and not really useful in this context.

Comment: I did that, of course.  It's just annoying not to be able to do `break _start`.  And gdb has a few other inconveniences when it doesn't have a "function name" to associate with an address.

Comment: Just because the CPU supports marking pages as no-execute doesn't mean that the operating system will do that.

Comment: Anyway, I tried it myself, and was also surprised that it worked.  `strace` matches the comments for your mmap args:  `mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0) = 0x7ff13bf6e000`, so IDK what's going on.  I'm on a normal Ubuntu system with "NX (Execute Disable) protection: active" according to `dmesg`.

Comment: @RossRidge: Right, but the surprise here is that we thought Linux *did* default to doing that when the hardware made it possible with low overhead.  [from the "Notes" section of the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html#NOTES):  "On some hardware architectures (e.g., i386), PROT_WRITE implies PROT_READ.  It is architecture dependent whether PROT_READ  implies  PROT_EXEC  or  not.
       Portable programs should always set PROT_EXEC if they intend to execute code in the new mapping."

Comment: I found this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730643/why-in-mmap-prot-read-equals-prot-exec.  Apparently this is the standard behaviour.  Probably too many programs that JIT some code broke when `PROT_EXEC` wasn't implied, so it's the default.  That's probably configurable (at compile-time if not at run-time).  I have to head out now for Ultimate (Frisbee), but I'll have another look when I get back.

Comment: Well, I see, its a duplicate, but this actually does not answer the question how to prevent it properly :/

Comment: That's correct, the other question is in need of a better answer.

Comment: The other question has [the answer in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730643/why-in-mmap-prot-read-equals-prot-exec#comment54326030_33141077).